# Что такое ожидание блокировки в Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

Добрый день.
Изучаю сейчас потоки исполнения в Java.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данном скриншоте изображенны состояния потока исполнения.

Мне остается не понятнм состояние "Ожидание блокировки"(Waiting for lock) и "Блокировка полученна"(Lock acquired). Может у меня что то не улаживается в голове. Как я понял поток может быть заблокированна например когда пытается получить доступ к методу который сейчас используется другим потоком, тоесть использует монитор.
  Можете обьяснить или привести пример каким образом поток ждет блокировки? Как так может быть что бы поток работал, потом стал ждать блокировки, а потом лишь получил саму блокировку? И почему нарисвоанна стрелочка от состояния BLOCKED к RUNNABLE с состоянием блокировка полученна?

Answer (score 0):

На этой диаграмме состояния это прямоугольники со скругленными краями, а стрелки - это переходы между состояниями. Это события, которые изменяют состояние потока.

`Waiting for lock` (иногда также называют `acquiring lock`) это не состояние, а *событие*, которое случается тогда, когда поток выполняет операцию захвата блокировки (монитора), например, вызывает метод с ключевым словом **synchnonized**. В результате этого события поток переходит в состояние **BLOCKED**, т.е. он заблокирован и ожидает, когда монитор захваченный другим потоком освободится. И когда это случается, то происходит событие `lock acquired`, поток захватывает блокировку, и может дальше исполнятся. Происходит переход в состояние **RUNNABLE** (готов исполняться).